# iDangerous Swiper slide error when window resize

Tags: swiper.js

**html**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide red ">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide blue">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide green">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            speed: 400,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: 5000,
            effect: 'fade'
        });
```

**bug recur steps**

1. open this page in two tab A tab:A,B
2. activate Tab A
3. change Tab A window size
4. wait Tab A swiper switch to next slider
5. switch to Tab b, slide error

**jsbin live demo**

[js bin live demo](http://output.jsbin.com/racuni)

**github demo**

https://github.com/ningshen/swiper-resize0bug

Comment: bug screen shot here: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ningshen/swiper-resize0bug/master/img/bug.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ningshen/swiper-resize0bug/master/img/bug.png)

Comment: steps screenshot gif:  [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ningshen/swiper-resize0bug/master/img/bug.gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ningshen/swiper-resize0bug/master/img/bug.gif)